# __autoload function not loading classes in directory

Tags: php, function, class, oop

I recently started learning object oriented programming so a lot of the stuff I am learning right now it relatively new to me. Anyway I am trying to load all of the classes in my classes folder '/classes/' but when the code is run I get an error when trying to access one of the files.

```
function __autoload($className)
{
    if(file_exists(DIR_FS_CLASSES . "class." . $className . ".php"))
        include DIR_FS_CLASSES . "class." . $className . ".php";
}
```

I have DIR_FS_CLASSES defined as 'classes/'

Comment: We will need a bit more information. What is the error message exactly?

Comment: @Turnerj I am not receiving an error for some reason but when I try to access one of the classes like `$db = new DatabaseConnect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);` it gives me an error saying it wasnt found

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: There are a lot of versions of PHP5, can you provide the minor version number too? eg. 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6?

Comment: @Turnerj PHP 5.3.28 ..

Comment: I'm curious to know where you have the autoload function.

Comment: @Dimitri I keep it in a PHP file that I include in all of the files

Comment: OK, thanks for that. [Looking at the doc for `__autoload`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php), you seem to be doing it correctly. Double check that the path is correct that it is generating. There is a chance the `file_exists` check fails because the path is incorrect that way what you described would occur.

Comment: @Turnerj It appears to be working. It outputs `classes/class.**classname**.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't give this a try and see if this works.

```
function my_autoloader($class){
    require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/classes/".'class.' . $class . '.php' );
}
spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

It could possibly be that the path is incorrect.

Comment: This actually gives me a path error unlike the other one but I have checked the path and even though it exists I am still receiving an error

Comment: And you're certain that the class filename is `class.MyClass.php` ?

Comment: definetly, when I echo the path I get **/home/siteName/public_html/siteName/includes/classes/class.CLASSNAME.php**

Comment: I also checked the permissions already and they do appear to allow the server to read them

Comment: I think you're probably missing the `includes` path/folder. Could that be?

Comment: I have it here `include DIR_FS_CLASSES . "class." . $className . ".php";`

Comment: Try my example but write it with the includes path.

 `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/classes/".'class.' . $class . '.php' );`

This really just looks like a path problem 'cause I don't see any other issue...